# How do I make a cheat-code permanent on Knoppix 8.6.1?

Tags: boot, knoppix, halt

**Summary:**

How do I make the following cheat-code permanent on knoppix 8.6.1 on usb stick,
because filesystem type is iso9660 (read-only) and won't let me edit
/mnt-system/boot/isolinux/isolinux.cfg.

**Cheat code entered at boot prompt:** knoppix xmodule=vesa

**Full Details:**

I've just put knoppix 8.6.1 on a usb stick (persistence was there by default).
But X Window won't display unless I enter the cheat-code "knoppix xmodule=vesa"
at the initial boot prompt.

Incidentally, when using Knoppix 7.7.1 on a usb stick, on the EXACT SAME laptop
(Acer Aspire 5755G), I don't need the cheat-code.

I'd like to **not have to type the cheat-code in every time** I boot the 8.6.1, and
believe that I can achieve that by adding "xmodule=vesa" as a kernel parameter
on an "APPEND" line in /boot/isolinux/isolinux.cfg.

I can get to that file using the path
/mnt-system/boot/isolinux/isolinux.cfg.

**But it won't let me write** to that file because /mnt-system is mounted read
only. When I try to remount /mnt-system as read-write, it says "write-protected."

/UNIONFS **is** mounted as read-write, but the path /UNIONFS/boot/isolinux/ does not
exist.

I understand that because partition 1 (the main Knoppix system) is filesystem
type iso9660*, that it is by definition read-only. (*On which I believe
/boot/isolinux/isolinux.cfg sits).

**Main Question:**

So could you tell me please, what method I need to use to make my cheat-code
permanent?

**Reason for Using 8.6.1:**

I'm trying out 8.6.1 because it has a newer kernel than 7.7.1, and I've read
that a newer kernel might fix my problem of downloads halting when the lid is
closed. I've already tried many lid disabling methods, but none of them prevent
the downloading from halting.

Comment: I think the term "kernel parameter" would be more appropriate than "cheat code" (which reminds me of games).

Comment: @Jeff Schaller: I agree completely. I don't like the term "cheat code" either. I would have
used a term like "kernel parameter", but it occurred to me that users would more
**readily understand** what my question was specifically about* if I used the term
"cheat code". (*That is, the thing you type in at the Knoppix boot prompt to
fix boot problems). **I'm more likely to get answers** when users **readily** know what
my question is specifically about. By the way - love the surname.